# a sun? is it right to say?

Tags: word-choice, articles

I recently read a famous motivational quote :

> "If you want to shine like a sun, burn like a sun"

As per my knowledge here the usage of article *a* is completely wrong, because there is only one sun, ahh! at least for us.

Please tell me whether it is right to say like this or the quote is wrong.

Comment: Can't help with grammar but astronomically, there is more than one sun. However, how is it motivational to burn like a sun? radiate like a sun maybe... but burn?

Comment: @Jalene I knew someone is going to point out that there are more than one suns and that is why I proactively mentioned in the question "at least for us" -it is one. Now coming to burning like sun it is referred to hard work- Say, you will have to burn (work hard) if you want to shine (achieve success) .

Comment: Say "as far as I know", not "as per my knowledge".

Comment: @tchrist hey thank you for the correction. But could you please tell me what is the difference. I am little bit weak in English

Comment: Not all dictionaries give the sense (1b)  that [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sun) quite rightly does: << **sun** noun **1a** often capitalized : the luminous celestial body around which the earth and other planets revolve ...
**1b:**  a celestial body like the sun: [a] star >>. This sense is often literary / poetic; it is often not the chosen sense, as ambiguity might arise. _But ELU expects signs of reasonable research, even a link to say Lexico saying 'they don't have a relevant definition'._

Comment: Please see [How on Earth can we say 'a' moon?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202448/how-on-earth-can-we-say-a-moon)

Comment: @Jalene "burn" here does not mean *undergo combustion*, it means *radiate light* (*shine*).

Comment: From the four close votes it has already accumulated I would say that your question is about to crash and burn. Whether this is like the Sun or a sun, we leave you to judge.

Comment: @David Ohh Really!

Comment: @Shrikant did you look at the 'a moon' question?

Comment: Please be aware that *as per my knowledge* isn’t “real English”. For details please see the answers to such questions as
[1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/256),
[2](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/6473),
[3](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/20525).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sun in Merriam-Webster means

> **1 a** *often capitalized* : the luminous celestial body around which the earth and other planets revolve, from which they receive heat and light, which is composed mainly of hydrogen and helium, and which has a mean distance from earth of about 93,000,000 miles (150,000,000 kilometers), a linear diameter of 864,000 miles (1,390,000 kilometers), and a mass 332,000 times greater than earth
>
> **b** : a celestial body like the sun : STAR

Under sense 1b it can mean any star and so "a sun" is fine.

Sense 3 is the same dictionary is

> **3** : one resembling the sun (as in warmth or brilliance)

So the quotation makes sense (no pun intended).